# Cross domain iframe control/loading with Jquery/CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, cross-domain

I need to embed my website onto another website, but remove the header and footer from my website and essentially just show the content.

The iframe gets built fine and loads the content into the page, and using an `onload event`, I've set the visibility so that the '`flashing`' is removed on load. Separately in a JS file, I'm then removing the header and footer on document ready, which seems to remove them prior to the visibility kicking in. On the first load, everything works fine. When you navigate in the iframe, clicking a link, for instance, the `window reloads` with the correct information, except for a few seconds, it loads the header and footer and the removes them.

Ideally, the header and footer should never be shown at all.

The `onload` event is inline JS with the iframe, whilst the document ready is loaded when the iframe is loaded.

The document ready code (external Js)

```
   if (window.location !== window.parent.location) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.header').remove();
            $('.footer').remove();
        }, 500);
    }
```

and the code to be embedded onto the separate domain/website:

```
<script>
function loadIframe() {
   var ifr = document.getElementById("mySite"); 
   ifr.style.height = '75vh'; 
}
</script>

<iframe style="visibility:hidden;" id="mySite" onload="loadIframe()" class="catalog-frame" src="http://xxxxxxx.com/about" width="100%">
</iframe>
```

Essentially, and perhaps the easiest way to manage this would be to, on change of the URL inside the iframe, hide the contents, then `onload`, show them again, but I'm having trouble detecting whether the URL inside the iframe is about to change/changing, to hide the content/hide the iframe.

As I have access to the actual contents being loaded into the `iframe`, is there actually a simpler solution here, although I will not have control over the parent domain?

Answer (score 0):

As  you mentioned you have no control on parent, so in my opinion you can do the following:

Add a `script` tag in your document's `head` as following:

```
if (window.location !== window.parent.location) {
        $("body").css("display", "none");
        //$("loading-pic").css("display", "block");
    }
```

Then at the bottom of you body, add the following script for the function on ready function:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('.header').remove();
   $('.footer').remove();
   //$("loading-pic").css("display", "none");
   $("body").css("display", "block");
});
```

What should happen this way is: Whenever you will click any link on iFrame, nothing will be shown, and when the document would be ready, our last script will remove header and footer and then display the body.

You can also show a loading-pic while your content is being loaded.

Alternatively, you use a variable to store whether the current session is in iFrame or on a separate window, and send it as GET or POST with your each link and remove the header and footer from server side if required.